# How do I stop execution in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to debug a problem occurring in an e2e test. using try/catch.
The page is written in vue.js
The console.log seems to keep on going long after execution has stopped, making it impossible to read the output.
Is there any way I can definitively stop execution at this point?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints